# Xamarin can't find Profile 78

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

Trying to run my Xamarin project on OSX El Capitan I get:

```
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.2.4/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.Common.targets: Warning: Unable to find framework corresponding to the target framework moniker '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile78'. Framework assembly references will be resolved from the GAC, which might not be the intended behavior.
```

Where does profile 78 come from?

I have installed Xamarin from the Universal installer

Answer (score 0):

Check your .csproj file for framework and profile settings.

You're looking for lines like:

```
<TargetFrameworkProfile>Profile111</TargetFrameworkProfile>
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

For some reason I found - as did some others here on SO - that these can go wonky. The only solution I found it manually edit the .csproj file.

I found [this site](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/05/framework-profiles-in-net.html) an invaluable resource to figure out framework and profile matchings and how to work on fixing mismatches. You may have to manually install further framework versions.

As a diagnostic step, always try to create a simple Hello World project with minimal dependencies (but the same target framework) to make sure it isn't your actual installation that is broken.

If that *doesn't* work you have a good indication that your entire installation/development environment somehow is broken or incomplete. A re-installation may be the easiest way.

However, if the *Hello World* works, you know that it's just your original project. In that case I've successfully - and carefully - copied my source from the original project over, renaming where needed. References and other dependencies, also options and configuration settings I adjust step by step, always watching if any might not be the trigger that caused the original breakage.

Comment: TargetFrameworkVersion was set to v4.5
TargetFrameworkProfile was Profile78
Changed to Profile111 but get:

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.2.4/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.Common.targets: Warning: Unable to find framework corresponding to the target framework moniker '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111'. Framework assembly references will be resolved from the GAC, which might not be the intended behavior. (LYG-di)

Comment: Yep, that's where the fun begins. :( As I wasn't sure yet that I was probably on the right track I didn't provide a link that may help. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks Marakai

I did a search of my Mac for Profile78 and found the path:

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.2.4/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78

It contains mostly .Net DLLs

Why can't Xamarin find this path?

Comment: Look at one of your comments _/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.2.4/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.Common.‌​targets_ and  the other _/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.2.4/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NE‌​TPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78_. The path on disk and your project path aren't lining up.

Comment: Tried readding .Net runtime in Preferences. Mapped to /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.2.4 but still the same result

Comment: Getting the nasty feeling your installation is borked.Have you tried a simple grounds-up Hello World sample app? Does that work? If not, there's a good sign things are messed up. If yes, and you don't want to go through further agony, try copy-pasting the files from your main project into a working test project, obviously renaming as needed. I've had to that once when .csproj files got utterly messed up and I saw no other way out.

Comment: Good pick up. Creating a new project seems to work. I'll start from there.

Comment: Cool, I'll put that into the answer as comments disappear over time.